# Create an excel worksheet based on a predefined excel template

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an .xls file which I call it model. Now my probleme is that I want to create over 50 .xls file that have that same format of the model. So properly my question is : how do I create a worksheet (excel file) based on an excel template using java? Is there is any way to do it without copying the style between sheets ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example does not use a pre defined template but you can go check out my code and morph it into something worth for you.
https://github.com/ernst223/spread-sheet-exporter

So you can maybe code the style in my class and then use my class for all of your excel files

```
SpreadSheetExporter spreadSheetExporter = new SpreadSheetExporter(List<Object>, "Filename");
File fileExcel = spreadSheetExporter.getExcel();
```

Answer (score 0):

as you didn't make any apparent effort before asking i will do the same
[excel api](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=excel%20java%20api)

Comment: Yes actually I tried to use apache velocity but it did not work and I tried to use apache POI but also I found no solution ! but  this can happen using "vba" so now I am trying to implimen vba code in a java code !